# Component gets outside of flex container

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, styles

I have a problem with styling a component, which has more height than the flex container it's in. What I want to achieve, is that if component has more height than the flex container, a scroll is appearing for the component. The footer should always stay at the bottom of the parent container. I know that adding `height: 0` to the table element from the example below fixes the issue, but it seems like not the correct way to resolve it.

Stackblitz: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-myxsza?file=index.html`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-myxsza?file=index.html%60)

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.wraper1 {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.body {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.component-wraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* table {
  height: 0;
} */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wraper1">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="component-wraper">
        <table>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use overflow: auto in body

```
.body {
flex-grow: 1;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Footer is also visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your goal, but does `overflow: auto;` work on `wraper1`?

Comment: It does but that's not my goal as I want to have a scroll on the component, not the whole wrapper. The footer should be always visible, no matter the table height. The goal I want to achieve is visible after uncommenting style table{ height:0 }